# How can I get my html page to refresh upon completion of a django function?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

I keep getting an error related to the csrf token when I try to employ consecutive submissions, and refreshing the page seems to work. The purpose of the program is to create zip files, so I figured the easiest solution would be to have the web page automatically reloaded once the zip file is done being created from the function in the views.py file and available for the user to open. The main issue I'm having is how to actually do that.

Here is the code for my HTML file:

```
{% load static %}

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/styleSheet.css' %}">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edstore">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    <!--BOOTSTRAP ASSETS-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
       <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=""  method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="main_Body">
            <div class="section">
                <h1>Fileconverter</h1>
                <br>

                <label for="file_field" class="custom-file-upload">
                    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>Updload File(s)</label>
                <input type="FILE" id="file_field" name="file_field" class="file-upload_button" multiple>
                <label id="file_name"></label>
                <br>
                <br><br><br>
            
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="file-submit__button" id="submitButton"> <!--onclick="formDisableButton"-->

        </div>
    </form> 
</body>


<footer>
    <p>Click "Choose File(s)" and select the files you want to convert.</p>
    <p>Once you click "Submit" the job will start.</p>
    <p>Upon completion, a zip folder will be downloaded in your browser.</p>
    <p>Do not click the submit buttons multiple times. If the tab is loading, the job is being processed.</p>
</footer>

</html>


<script>

  document.querySelector("#file_field").onchange = function(){
  document.querySelector("#file_name").textContent = this.files[0].name;
  }

  const tempButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");
function formDisableButton(){
    tempButton.disabled = true;
    setTimeout(formEnableButton, 10000);
}

function formEnableButton(){
    tempButton.disabled = false;
}

    /*setTimeout(()=>{
        btn.disabled = false;
        console.log('Button Activated')
    }, 10000)*/


   /* $(function(){
        $("#submitButton").click(function(){
            $("#submitButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#submitButton").removeAttr("disabled");
            }, 10000)
        });
    });*/
```

And this is the code from my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from .forms import FileFieldForm
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .perform_conversion import FileConverter
import zipfile
import io


def FileFieldFormView(request, *args, **kwargs):
 
form = FileFieldForm(request.POST)
files = request.FILES.getlist('file_field')

if request.method == 'POST':
    print(request)
    form = FileFieldForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():

        
        zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()   
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, "w", False) as zip_file:
            
            for f in files:
                fileconverter = FileConverter(f.name)
                fileconverter.run(f.file)
                
                for img_name, img in fileconverter.output.items():
                
                    data = io.BytesIO(img)
                
                    zip_file.writestr(img_name, data.getvalue())
            
        # Set the return value of the HttpResponse
        response = HttpResponse(zip_buffer.getvalue(), content_type='application/octet-stream')
        # Set the HTTP header for sending to browser
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % 'zip.zip'
        response.set_signed_cookie('csrftoken', request.COOKIES['csrftoken'])
        
        
        # Return the response value
        return response

            
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Form Invalid')

else:
    return render(request, 'file_converter.html')
```

As a bonus if you're willing to provide a bit of extra help, I can't ever seem to have any sort of onclick for my submission button.  Every time I try to add it, the python files never actually end up running and the page just sits there. I'd like to have it so that when the submission button is clicked it is removed form the page to prevent excessive submission attempts and since, in theory, the page will be refreshing after a successful run through, the submit button will just be reposted onto the page.

Comment: There is no need for any page refresh, as you are processing the request in your view and returning the response

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to refresh the active django webpage without using return redirect(...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72968167/is-there-a-way-to-refresh-the-active-django-webpage-without-using-return-redirec)